# Chatbot customizing a reply message by gRPC

Tags: grpc, dialogflow-es

I am creating chatbots with DialogFlow, in the enterprise version a new form of communication between my server and the DialogFlow server, gRPC (grpc.io) was added, thus eliminating HTTP / Restful.

However as far as I understand the documentation, I still need to use HTTP / Restful to receive the user's intent, receive the recovered parameters and generate a response phrase using Fulfillment. I would like to know if I can still do this logic for the  gRPC and actually eliminate the use of HTTP.

PS: I never get answers in the official forum, so I'm posting here.

Comment: Please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve